# Is tls mutual authentication possible betwwen proxy and client with mitmproxy

Tags: python-3.x, websocket, proxy, mitmproxy

Does MiTM proxy support mutual authentication between Proxy and Client? All i need is to get the client certificate by sending a "CERTIFICATE_REQUEST" TLS handshake message from proxy. Is it possible achieve by any available options.

I want a solution. could mitmproxy has that ability if not suggest me some other tools

Answer (score 0):

A have not seen a proxy with support for HTTPS client certificate authentication. The only authentication HTTP proxies support is username/password which is added as [`Proxy-Authorization`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Proxy-Authorization) header field to the HTTP request which is then processed and removed by the proxy.

If you want a secure connection and authentication between client and proxy I recommend to you the [Mitmproxy wireguard mode](https://mitmproxy.org/posts/wireguard-mode/). If you start Mitmproxy in that mode it uses an integrated Wireguard server to establish the connection between client and proxy. Wireguard is a well known VPN system, therefore it's security is equivalent to an HTTPS client certificate authentication. On client systems you can use one of the official Wireguard clients.

Comment: can you tell me if  i have a client certificate and a server certificate how can i do tls mutual authentication using wireguard mode in mutual authentication? it would be great help

Comment: @jayS On Stackoverflow you can say thank you by upvoting and accepting an answer.